# Iterating through a list to create a table in Jinja, Python-Flask, SQLite

Tags: python, list, for-loop, variables, jinja2

I am trying to create a basic table using a `for loop` in Jinja, the data is a Python List due it being extracted from a SQLite database using `fetchall()`. Though I can't seem to find the right syntax.
I'd like the table to be something like:
Symbol | Name | Shares | Price |
AAPL   | Apple|    3   | $114.86|
TSLA   | Tesla|     2  | $214.04|

Here is my code so far:
Python:

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""
    with sqlite3.connect("finance.db") as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        user = session["user_id"][0]
        cur.execute("SELECT symbol, name, SUM(shares), price FROM transactions WHERE username=? GROUP BY symbol", (user[0],))
        index_table = cur.fetchall()
      
    return render_template("index.html", index_table=index_table)
```

`print(index_table)` outputs a list like this `[('AAPL', 'Apple, Inc.', 2, 119.95), ('TSLA', 'Tesla, Inc.', 12, 407.0)]`

Jinja template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}


{% block body %}

<table>
{% for row in index_table %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row }}</td>
        <td> {{ row }}</td>
        <td> {{ row }}</td>
        <td> {{ row }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

I have also tried:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}


{% block body %}

<table>
{% for row in index_table %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
        <td> {{ row[1] }}</td>
        <td> {{ row[2] }}</td>
        <td> {{ row[3] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

This line from the Jinja documentation makes me wonder if Jinja only accepts Dictionaries and not Lists:
"Template variables are defined by the context dictionary passed to the template."
This sentence is a bit cryptic to me, but perhaps someone with more experience can explain it?

If this is the case, then I am not sure how I would go about mapping this list to a dictionary as its length and size will fluctuate. My understanding of dictionary comprehension is limited to...
`dictionary = {key:value for vars in iterable}`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, your 2nd example looks about right. What does the output look like?

Comment: Thanks Christian. The area of the webpage where the table should be is blank.

Comment: I'm wondering what else it could be. The other pages of this site are still working as expected, and they all feature some sort of Jinja: there is a separate page for register, login, quote and buy.

Answer (score 2):

Your 2nd example seems about right. You can iterate over any sequence in a Jinja template using `{% for item in seq %}..{% endfor %}` (see [docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for))

In your case, `item` is a list, which items can be accessed using either subscript syntax `row[n]` or even with attribute syntax `row.n`, where `n` is the 0-based index of the item in the list.

So this means that

```
<table>
  {%- for row in index_table %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
    <td>{{ row[3] }}</td>
  </tr>
  {%- endfor %}
</table>
```

is equal to

```
<table>
  {%- for row in index_table %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ row.0 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.3 }}</td>
  </tr>
  {%- endfor %}
</table>
```

Another option would be to unpack the items of the inner list:

```
<table>
  {%- for symbol, name, sum_shares, price in index_table %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ symbol }}</td>
    <td>{{ name }}</td>
    <td>{{ sum_shares }}</td>
    <td>{{ price }}</td>
  </tr>
  {%- endfor %}
</table>
```

Or, iterate over the inner list with a for-loop as well:

```
<table>
  {%- for row in index_table %}
  <tr>
    {%- for col in row %}
    <td>{{ col }}</td>
    {%- endfor %}
  </tr>
  {%- endfor %}
</table>
```

The examples have been tested with the following versions:

```
Flask==1.1.2
Jinja2==2.11.2
```

Comment: I really appreciate your comment. Unfortunately none of those options have solved the issue. Though it is reassuring that I had written the code correctly. I am wondering what else it could be... All of the other pages (register, login, quote and buy) are all working as expected.

Comment: Just solved it. It should have been `{% block main %}` not `{block body%]`. I really hope you don't feel like you wasted your time. Having the extra support was motivating and encouraged me persist and look at my code differently. So thank you for that.